# Android - Managing Multiple Wifi Connections

Tags: android, android-networking, wifi-direct

I'm in the design phase of an Android application that will require a connection to multiple wifi networks, and I'm wondering if anyone can provide advice and/or code snippets regarding the best way to go about this. The app will have a connection to one wifi network that has internet access, and another wifi network with no internet access that will be used to share data accross the devices (raspberry pis) on it.

Can I be connected to both networks simultaneously? If so, how do I specify which network to use when making a request? I've been reading the [Android 5.0 documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless) which indicates its possible, but I'm a little confused on how to implement it.

If its not possible, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232363/connect-android-to-two-wireless-networks-simultaneously) post from 2011 says that the WiFi Direct standard could be another solution. WiFi Direct is now supported on Android, but I can't find many examples of how to use it to achieve my goal.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can have only one connection to the Access point, meaning that you can indeed make the device connected to the access point which offers you the internet connection, but then you can not connect to other networks.

Anyway, I would suppose that in your use case that is not the problem, actually I don't see any problems there. At least, if you simply have the connection and then have the Raspberry Pi's connected to you, i.e. you simply create a access point in your Android device, and all devices connect to it.